# Waiting for the command to complete in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and trying to develop a small application which internally opens a command prompt and executes some command here. This is what I have done so far:

```
    m_command = new Process();
    m_command.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
    m_command.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    m_command.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    m_command.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    m_command.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    m_command.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    m_command.Start();

    m_reader = m_command.StandardOutput;
    m_writer = m_command.StandardInput;

    m_writer.WriteLine("Somecommand"); //execute some command
```

As you can see, I have redirected the input and output. My question is how do I execute the "some command" synchronously i.e. I want to read the result of my command using the redirected output. For that I have to wait until the command I invoked using WriteLine to complete. How do I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That really depends on what the command will do. You could wait for the process to exit with `Process.WaitForExit`, while simultaneously reading from `m_reader` in another thread or with `OutputDataReceived`. That will only work if the process is going to quit when the command has finished though. (Note that you *have* to read the output, otherwise it could fill up the output buffer and basically block the process.)

The other option is if you'll get a certain bit of output when the command has finished - such as the next command prompt. The trouble is that if your command happens to output the same thing, you'll get it wrong.

It feels like launching a command prompt like this isn't a great approach though. Any reason you don't create a separate process each time?

Another option: if you can work out what process you've just launched *via* the command line, you could find that as a `Process` and wait for *that* to exit. It's tricky though - I really would try to redesign your solution.

Answer (score 9):

You can call

```
 m_command.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: But I don't want my command window to close. I want to reuse the same command prompt again for executing some other command. Will this method still work?

Comment: That'll wait until the cmd.exe closes, but ignore the end of "somecommand".

Comment: You can always add m_writer.WriteLine("exit");

Comment: @Philippe: I think you misunderstood the question; as I understand it Naveen whants to execute a command in the command prompt that the code has launched, and wait for *that* command to finish.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I used in a small project I made:

```
processStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = command;

// Start the process with the info we specified.
    // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
    using(Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to put all commands into a .cmd file, execute that and use

```
 Process.Start("cmdfile").WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the prompt in the output.

Quite tricky too.